# 3D charts in silverlight 4 without using 3rd party control

Tags: silverlight, charts

Is it possible to create 3D charts in silverlight 4 without using 3rd party control?

Comment: Simple answer is "yes". The more complex answer is that it will take a fair bit of effort - why do you think there are 3rd party controls?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Controls from 3rd party like ComponentArt are available to do that. But the limitation that we faced was they were not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [PlaneProjections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.planeprojection%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to get a 3D effect  or you would have to use [Silverlight 5 (in beta at the moment) which supports a 3D API](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/MED06).

In both cases you will need to program the chart completely.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, sure it is possible but is it worth your time when you could buy a great looking one that provides support? Telerik has a wide variety of 3D Charts that you can review at the links provided below:

**Bar Charts**

[3D Bar](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Bar) , [3D Stacked Bar](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedBar) ,  [3D Stacked Bar 100 Series](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedBar100)

**Line Charts**

[3DLine](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Line), [3D Stacked Line](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedLine)

**Area Charts**

[3D Area](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Area) , [3D Stacked Area](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedArea) , [3D Stacked Area 100 Series](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/StackedArea100)

**Pie Charts**

[3D Doughnut](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Doughnut) , [3D Pie](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Chart/Gallery3D/Pie)

Disclaimer: I work at Telerik as a XAML Evangelist.