# Silverlight : Creating 3D Chart

Tags: silverlight, xaml, charts, visual-studio-2013, silverlight-toolkit

I want to create a 3D Chart, Is it possible to create it using silverlight 5 toolkit(or any free tool) ? 
Can I make a 3D Chart using expression Blend??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A 3d chart is basically a complex line drawing. Sure, Silverlight can do that. There are no charts components that ship with the Silverlight toolkit though. There are commercial components like Telerik RadCharts that offer 3D charts for Silverlight (http://www.telerik.com/products/silverlight/chart.aspx). There are some non-3D-components available for free (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/torstenmandelkow/archive/2013/05/06/free-modernui-charts-for-wpf-windows-store-apps-und-silverlight-published.aspx).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8018356/736079